# Is this book a reliable source for beginning Java EE?

Tags: java, books, jsp

[Core Servlets and Javaserver Pages: Core Technologies, Vol. 1 (2nd Edition)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0130092290)

Can I rely on this book to learn Servlets and JSP,or is there a better book out there I should be reading instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to try the Head First series by Bert Bates and Kathy Sierra.  They're particularly geared towards being brain friendly (e.g. Easy to digest).

Comment: ...but take a look inside first. Some people really like the hands on approach of the Head First series, it is cool and their explanations tend to stuck to the brain. But there are other people having problems with that (including me). It really depends on what type of learner you are. The 2nd edition of that particular book has still a few print errors in the code portions.

Comment: does this book have any particular advantage than the book in question?

Comment: @Phobia - The HF series are designed to be 'brain friendly'.  Basically Bert and Kathy have done quite a bit of study on how people learn technical subjects effectively and their HF series reflects that (open one up in a book store, you'll see it's very different to your traditional tech book).  I's not for everyone, but they've sold a ton of books and have a passionate following

Comment: I know,I have read their Kathy's book about SCJP and I liked it,but I can't buy this book right now,so I'm asked about the differences between the two books,to see if there's a topic I'll be missing by reading the other book

Comment: @Phobia Ah, not sure in that case sorry.

Answer (score 1):

JEE is a vast area, hence, can't be included in a single book. But, to learn about JSPs and Servelt, you can follow K&B's [Head First JSP and Servlet](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0596005407) book. It's the recommended book for Sun's SCWCD exam.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle covers both JSP and Servlet under SCWCD exam. The exam objective fully covers the advanced concepts so better you may prepare for SCWCD certification exam. It gives you deep knowledge in concepts. In my experience I said it, the certification help me more to go to next level in my carrier.

An excellent material I refer you that one I used for my preparation. I hope this is the only one material enough for your preparation, because it has both study guide and also sample mock exams.

The Exam Objectives are explained with example programs in this study guide so you can easily and quickly learn the concepts. I used EPractize Labs **[SCWCD 5](http://www.epractizelabs.com/certification/sun/scwcd-exam-5.html)** Certification Training Lab for my preparation.

For more details read the [scwcd 5 preparation](http://www.epractizelabs.com/blog2/?p=140) article.